Proving that $ \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2} $ by using the definition of a limit
I want to prove by definition that
$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2}
$
What I have done:
$
\left| \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x^2} - \frac{1}{2} \right| = \left| \frac{2(1 - \sqrt{1 + x^2}) - x^2}{2x^2} \right|
$
I want to bound this expression in such a way that I can use the hypothesis $ |x| < \delta $, but I don't know how. After that, I know that I need to give a specific value to $ \delta $ in order to bound it. That part I can do, I just need to know how to bound the absolute value expression. Any hint?

Hint: Multiply the numerator and denominator by $1+\sqrt{1-x^2},$ before you subtract $1/2.$

FYI, substituting $x$ to $\sin x$ can make your numerator $1-\cos x$, which you may have seen often.

@RDK I feel like the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos x}{\sin^2 x}$ is harder, not easier, than this limit. I might be tempted to solve it by the substitution $u = \sin x$...

@MishaLavrov Well, my comment was ‘just for information’, not easier way. $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac {1-\cos x}{\sin^2 x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac {1-\cos x}{x^2} \cdot \dfrac {x^2}{\sin^2 x}$ seemed interesting for me.

You have a typo. ($+ \to -$) on the right hand side of the equality above. Note that $2-x^2-2\sqrt{1-x^2} = ( \sqrt{1-x^2}-1)^2 $.

@Misha Well, you can multiply RDK's expression by $\frac{1+\cos x}{1+\cos x}$ to get rid of the $\sin^2 x$. But that's basically equivalent to Thomas's approach.

@copper.hat But when I want to bound the expression by delta, where should I use it? Because I don't get any absolute value, do I need to assign an auxiliary value to delta to bound it? It doesn't end up in terms of delta or epsilon

If you follow Thomas Andrews' approach and add a few more steps you'll end up with something that can be bounded by a constant times $x^2$

@C25 Perhaps combine hints from my comment and Thomas Andrews' approach.

Multiply the numerator and denominator by $1+\sqrt{1-x^2}$ :
$\frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x^2} 
= \frac{ ( 1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}  ) ( 1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2} )}{x^2 ( 1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2} )}
= \frac{1-(1-x^2)}{x^2 ( 1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}  )}
= \frac{x^2}{x^2 ( 1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}  )}
= \frac{1}{ 1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2} }
$
Then subtract by $1/2$ :
$ \frac{1}{ 1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}  }- \frac12
= \frac{ 2 - (1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2})  }{ 2  \left(1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}\right)  }
= \frac{  1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}   }{ 2  \left(1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}\right)  }
= \frac{  (1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}) (1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2})   }{ 2  \left(1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}\right) \left(1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}\right)  }
= \frac{  1 - (1 - x^2)    }{ 2  \left(1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}\right) ^2  }
= \frac{  x^2   }{ 2  \left(1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}\right) ^2  }
$
Within the domain $[-1,1]$ we have $1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2} \geq 1 $, therefore
$ \left|\frac{1}{ 1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}  }- \frac12 \right| = \left| \frac{  x^2   }{ 2  \left(1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}\right) ^2  } \right|
\leq \left| \frac{  x^2   }{ 2 (1)^2 } \right| = \left| \frac{  x^2   }{ 2  } \right|
$
If one chooses $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon}$ then for $|x|<\delta$,
$ \left|\frac{1}{ 1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}  }- \frac12 \right| = \left| \frac{  x^2   }{ 2  \left(1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}\right) ^2  } \right|
\leq \left| \frac{  x^2   }{ 2  } \right| < \left| \frac{  \delta^2   }{ 2  } \right| = \left| \frac{  \epsilon  }{ 2  } \right| < \epsilon 
$

Using the definition of a limit
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
for any $\epsilon>0$, exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x|<\delta$, then
$$
\left| \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x^2} - \frac12\right| < \epsilon.
$$
Being
$$
\left| \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}} - \frac{1}{2} \right| = \left| \frac{2 - (1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2})}{2(1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2})} \right| = \left| \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{2(1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2})} \right|.
$$
and using the Taylor expansion for $\sqrt{1 - x^2}$ around $x = 0$ we have:
$$
\sqrt{1 - x^2} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^4) \iff 
1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2} = \frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^4).
$$
Then as $x \to 0$, the numerator behaves like $\frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^4)$ and the denominator is close to $2$. For small $x$, we can approximate:
$$
\left| \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{2(1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2})} \right| \approx \frac{\frac{x^2}{2}}{2} = \frac{x^2}{4}.
$$
To satisfy the condition:
$$
\frac{x^2}{4} < \epsilon \implies x^2 < 4\epsilon \implies |x| < 2\sqrt{\epsilon}.
$$
Setting $\delta = 2\sqrt{\epsilon}$, we have:
$$
0 < |x| < \delta \implies \left| \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x^2} - \frac{1}{2} \right| < \epsilon.
$$

If you’re willing to use a Taylor expansion, then you could just do so at the outset and the result is immediate.

@SBK Dear user, I simply read the question and it does not say that you cannot use Taylor derivatives or expansions.

Sorry, I’m just saying that you could Taylor expand the original $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ before any manipulations.
